# Issue with subdomain and domain

Tags: html, .htaccess, dns

I am using `www.ohlookawebsite.com` and `www.stumemes.ohlookawebsite.com`

If you visit `ohlookawebsite.com` it will take you to `www.stumemes.ohlookawebsite.com`
If you visit `stumemes.ohlookawebsite.com` it will take you to `www.ohlookawebsite.com`

I've tried editing `htaccess` to force `www.` but it just forces users onto `www.ohlookawebsite.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addthis to your `.htaccess`.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ohlookawebsite\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.ohlookawebsite.com [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stumemes\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.stumemes.ohlookawebsite.com [R,L]
```

Comment: I've added this to the .htaccess but it's still doing the redirect issue

Comment: @obkso What issue. Give details.

Comment: Well I've updated the .htaccess to the above but it still redirects randomly. When I go to `ohlookawebsite.com` I want it to go to `www.ohlookawebsite.com` and when I go to `stumemes.ohlookawebsite.com` I want it to go to `www.stumemes.ohlookawebsite.com`

I didn't know if it is doing the opposite with the above code, but I've switched it around and it's still redirecting

Comment: @obkso Yes the code above did it the opposite way as asked in question. I have changed it now. And tested it. It works fine here. Are you on a shared host? and is `mod_rewrite` enabled? do you have any other rewrite rules?

Comment: Yeah I changed it to what you've changed it to now, and it still didn't work. I believe I am on a shared host. I'm not sure, Is there any way to check? I used to have .htaccess to force www. but that was when I didn't have a subdomain

Comment: @obkso If you do not have access to apache's conf file. Then you usually are on a shared host. Check your server configurations because, the code above is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Probably its in apache vhosts (you need to ask your hosting to change it) or in dns settings of your domain. In short something (one of above) is checking www and does redirect before your httaccess is parsed.